# How to enable static GZip compression for versioned "/style.css?v=1" resourcess in IIS?

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, compression, gzip

Google PageSpeed reports that files like `.css` and `.js` are compressed, but `.css?v=1` and `.js?v=1` are not.

How to enable static compression for files that have a dynamically changing version number in the URL?